# AWS Ubuntu add user with password authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, deployment

We have a ubuntu AWS instance and we login with ubuntu user with a pem key.

What we want to do is to create a user called deploy and we want to ssh into the server using deploy using a password and without the pem key.

How can we do that

```
sudo adduser deploy --home /home/deploy --shell /bin/bash
```

This asked for the password and I provided with one

However when I run the following from my mac

```
ssh deploy@<ip-address-of-aws-ubuntu-machine>
```

It says Permission denied (public key)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible. I'd highly recommended using key authentication for this user also because it's much more secure but if you insist on using a password you have to enable password auth in your `sshd_config` usually found at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Change this line:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

To

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Did you leave `PubkeyAuthentication yes`? yes for both is the default SSH configuration and should work fine. Maybe paste your `sshd_config`?